# How to create this kind of crosstab by Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

The data looks like:

```
bad score1 score2
1    80-90  70-80
0    90-100 80-90
1    70-80  90-100
1    70-80 70-80
0    70-80 70-80
1    80-90  70-80
```

The result should be like the total number of 'the bad flag is 1 when it is in the corresponding range of socre1 and score2'. For example:

```
       70-80 80-90 90-100 (score2)
70-80   1     0       1
80-90   2     0       0
90-100  0     1       0
(score1)
```

I know the pd.crosstab has the similar function, but it can not solve my issue.

```
pd.crosstab(df.score1, df.score2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `values` and`aggfunc`, combined with [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
out = (pd.crosstab(df.score1, df.score2, values=df['bad'], aggfunc='sum')
         .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
)
```

Output:

```
score2  70-80  80-90  90-100
score1                      
70-80       1      0       1
80-90       2      0       0
90-100      0      0       0
```

Comment: @jezrael is it? Op asked about a `crosstab`

Comment: @jezrael In the end, I think crosstab uses a `pivot_table` internally

Comment: @jezrael fair enough. I'm also adding the `pivot` one for clarity